# Translating multi-level mongodb documents into Backbone.js Models/Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

My mongodb collections contain documents and embedded documents at two key levels, posts and comments. Below is a single post document containing 2 comments as embedded documents.

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("502d7b33eac728b658000002"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("502d7b39eac728b658000003"),
            "body" : "comment 1",
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("502d7d1feac728b658000004"),
            "body" : "comment 2",
            "votes" : 0
        }
    ],
    "text" : "post 1",
}
```

I would like to map this structure into a Backbone.js PostCollection, PostModel, CommentCollection and CommentModel, where a PostModel contains a CommentCollection. I would also like this to be preserved each time that I call fetch() on PostCollection or PostModel, as that will synchronize from a REST API.

I would also like listen to Backbone.js "change" and "add" events on all the collections and models I have specified above.

What would be the way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational), it contains code for relating between models and collection using HasOne and HasMany logic.